# Apache Virtual Hosts Not Working

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, virtualhost

**EDIT: I was able to get this to work.  There was a VirtualHost entry in httpd.conf that was effecting the Virtual Hosts in my vhosts.conf file.**

I am trying to set up a CentOS server and configure it with two virtual hosts.  This server is going to be replacing a Solaris server with the same settings.  On the Solaris (current) server, the virtual hosts work, but on the new server, the first one is called regardless of what sent it (modifying hosts file).

SSL virtual host works.

I have tried to add "NameVirtualHost *:80", but get

> [Thu Jun 30 14:43:38 2011] [warn] *default* VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
>   [Thu Jun 30 14:43:38 2011] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts

Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: I forgot to post my configurations.

> NameVirtualHost *:80
>   ...
>   `<VirtualHost *:80>`
>       DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/domain1"
>       ServerName domain1
>       ServerAlias www.domain1
>       
>           AllowOverride All
>           Options None
>           Order allow,deny
>           Allow from all
>       
>       DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
>   `</VirtualHost>`
>   `<VirtualHost *:80>`
>       DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/domain2"
>       ServerName domain2
>       ServerAlias www.domain2
>       
>           AllowOverride All
>           Options None
>           Order allow,deny
>       Allow from all
>       
>       DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
>   `</VirtualHost>`

Answer (score 1):

remove the NameVirtualHost *:80 or comment it #NameVirtualHost

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/304198)

Comment: @rnxrx why this not providing an answer? The log file say NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts so I told him to comment that and my answer was correct as you see from his Edit

Answer (score 0):

It'd be really helpful for you to post the configurations.  That said, you likely have the following as your vhost definitions:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
```

When your `NameVirtualHost *:80` block needs to match your `VirtualHost` definitions.  Try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Posted config above.  I have the *:80 in the virtual host directive.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've defined both of your VirtualHosts as:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com

...
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerName www.myothersite.com

...
</VirtualHost>
```

This is not what you want, you want two VirtualHost that listen on *:80, and use Name-Based Virtual Hosting, like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com

...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.myothersite.com

...
</VirtualHost>
```

The _default_:80 definition tells Name-Based Virtual Hosting to use this VirtualHost when no other VirtualHost matches by name or unique IP:Port pair.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Posted config above.  I have the *:80 already.